# Documentation generator for embedded C projects

Tags: microcontroller, c, firmware, mplabx, documentation

I'm looking for the equivalent of what [Javadoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) is to Java and from that, a way to standardize code documentation.  Is [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) more common in this context.  Are there built-in, IDE-dependent options? I'm interesting in documenting a project in MPLABX.

Comment: Doxygen is really a standard for anything else but Java (can also be used instead of Javadoc.)

Comment: DoxyGen indeed.
But, I've even seen programs where you put in your source code and they will generate class diagrams for your project.
But well, don't think it'll work for C that way, as it's does not really have classes.
Possibilities enough, but DoxyGen is preferred/most used, probably.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doxygen is the best option for generating documentation from code comments. It is also heavily used in industry to generate documentation for embedded C projects. If you are using MPLABX (which is actually a netbeans ide), there is plugin for doxygen available, see below link:
http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/14326/doxygen-integration

Comment: Unfortunately this plugin is not compatible with MPLABX.

Comment: Well, there is a DoxyGen stand-alone something, you have to specify your project folder and it will then create the output/documentary for it. (If you have the comment syntax right.)